# Adding a camera to follow 'player' movement in an ascii dungeon map

Tags: python, camera, ascii, game-engine

At the moment in my game every turn it display the whole map but I would like it to only to display the position of the player and maybe a 3x3 grid around the player. Any suggestions on how this can be done within the code below would be great.

I am assuming you'll have to change the display map function but I am not too sure how to print out just just a 3x3 grid around the player x and y.

```
import os 

#map
dungeonMap = [["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
              ["0",".",".","0",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".","0","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".","0",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".","0","*",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]

playerMap  = [["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
              ["0",".",".","0",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".","0","0"],
              ["0","S",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".","0",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".","0",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","0"],
              ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]


#Displaying the map
def displayMap(maps):
    for x in range(0,12):
        print(maps[x])

#selecting a map
mapChoice = dungeonMap

displayMap(playerMap)

#initialising the players position
position = mapChoice[0][0]


x = 1
y = 3

print(mapChoice[y][x])
while position != "E":
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    displayMap(playerMap)
    previousX = x
    previousY = y
    playerMap[y][x] = "."
    movement = input("W,S,D,A,MAP").upper()

    if movement == "W":
        y = y-1
        position = mapChoice[y][x]
        playerMap[y][x] = "S"
        

    if movement == "S":
        y = y+1
        position = mapChoice[y][x]
        playerMap[y][x] = "S"
        

    if movement == "D":
        x = x+1
        position = mapChoice[y][x]
        playerMap[y][x] = "S"
        

    if movement == "A":
        x = x-1
        position = mapChoice[y][x]
        playerMap[y][x] = "S"


    position = mapChoice[y][x]
    playerMap[y][x] = "S"
    
    if position == "0" or position == "1":
        print("You hit a wall, you stumble in the darkness back to your previous position...")
        playerMap[y][x] = "0"
        x = previousX
        y = previousY
        playerMap[y][x] = "S"
```

Answer (score 0):

Really?

```
def displayMapAround(maps,x,y):
  for dy in (-1,0,1):
    print( maps[y+dy][x-1:x+2] )
```

**Edit to show larger region**
The tricky part with using a larger region is that you have to check whether you're going past the edges.  You only have 1 element of padding there.  You generally want only odd sizes, otherwise the focus isn't in the center.

```
def displayMapAround(maps,size,x,y):
  assert( size & 1 ) # is size odd?
  x0 = max( 0, x-size//2 )
  x1 = min( x+size//2, len(maps[0]))
  y0 = max( 0, y-size//2 )
  y1 = min( y+size//2, len(maps))
  for dy in range(y0,y1+1):
    print( maps[dy][x0:x1+1] )
```

Comment: I am assuming it is suppose to be displayMapAround(maps,x,y) not displayMapAround(map,x,y): as map is a in built function ? .. When I implement the code doesn't seem to work as it transport me to the lower bottom corner of the map and I have some issues with some invisible walls

Comment: Sorry my mistake,  Yes your code does work, i am just wondering what do you need to change to change the grid size from 3x3 to let say 4x4 to 5x5 etc etc

Comment: You're right about map/maps.  I know better.  I'll edit it to show a larger region.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. You change the [x-1:x+2] section, thank you

Comment: Thanks for the second example showing the larger region.